# Change datetime format to hours only in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings date. Formatted in like

> Fri Apr 23 12:38:07 +0000 2021

How can I change its format? **I want to take only the hours.** I checked other source before, but you need to change the date format, which obviously I'm struggling rn

As I know, you can write the code like

```
ds['waktu'] =  pd.to_datetime(ds['tanggal'], format='%A %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
```

to change its format. But idk what +0000 means.

Comment: That 0000 represent timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only **want to take the hours from the date strings**, you can use [`.dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) after the `pd.to_datetime()` call, as follows:

```
ds['waktu'] = pd.to_datetime(ds['tanggal'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Note that your format string for `pd.to_datetime()` is not correct and need to replace `%A` by `%a`.

`+0000` is the time zone, which you can parse with `%z` in the format string.

### Demo

```
ds = pd.DataFrame({'tanggal': ['Fri Apr 23 12:38:07 +0000 2021', 'Thu Apr 22 11:28:17 +0000 2021']})

ds['waktu'] = pd.to_datetime(ds['tanggal'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

print(ds)


                          tanggal     waktu
0  Fri Apr 23 12:38:07 +0000 2021  12:38:07
1  Thu Apr 22 11:28:17 +0000 2021  11:28:17
```